# Why does using of print statement in Python3 reduce memory usage on leetcode?

Tags: python, memory

So I was solving the problem 11: Container With Most Water on leetcode and noticed something odd.

The problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/

Here is my solution:

```
class Solution:
    def maxArea(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
        max_water = 0
        p1 = 0
        p2 = len(height)-1

        while p1<p2:
            water = min(height[p1], height[p2]) * abs(p1-p2)
            if water > max_water:
                max_water = water

            if height[p1] <= height[p2]:
                p1 += 1
            elif height[p2] < height[p1]:
                p2 -= 1

        return max_water
```

Here is the same solution but with a print statement included in the while loop:

```
class Solution:
    def maxArea(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
        max_water = 0
        p1 = 0
        p2 = len(height)-1

        while p1<p2:
            print(p1, p2)
            water = min(height[p1], height[p2]) * abs(p1-p2)
            if water > max_water:
                max_water = water

            if height[p1] <= height[p2]:
                p1 += 1
            elif height[p2] < height[p1]:
                p2 -= 1

        return max_water
```

Here is the problem:
[submitted solutions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzrRu.png)
Notice that  every time I submit a solution with the print statement included, the runtime is slow as expected, but the memory usage is 26.x MB, vs when I submit a solution without the print statement, the runtime is fast but the memory usage increases to 27.x MB.

I do not understand why this is. I would think that including the print statement should not have any effect on the memory usage, and if any, it should increase the memory usage, right? So why is this happening? Am I thinking wrong? or is this something that happens only with leetcode? or is this because of how python works? Someone please enlighten me.

Thank you.

Comment: Any answer is going to be specific to whatever execution environment LeetCode uses. How is the code executed? What memory, exactly, are they measuring? (If I had to guess, it examines the code for writes to standard output. If there are none, it  accumulates in memory things that would otherwise be written to a file instead.)

Comment: I checked with the available solution in java. Using System.out.println(p1 + " " + p2); increases the memory usage from 82MB to 115 MB. So it works the other way in Java.

Comment: There's no reason why the Python and Java runtimes need to behave similarly. (Which makes the insistence of Python submissions requiring a non-idiomatic class definition all the more ridiculous.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about a closed-system's architectural design, not about programming.

Comment: You made an observation about behavior in Leetcode's runtime environment. Good. That should prompt you to try to reproduce the behavior in your own (laptop?) environment. If you locally obtain a similar result from instrumented code, please post it here so we can try to reproduce it and offer insights. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example